# integer overflow in kernel -- possible?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, integer-arithmetic

I have to do integer arithmetic in kernel, specifically I need to increment a `size_t` object by some delta, and this will happen quite often. So I'm wondering if I need to guard against possible integer overflows in the kernel, and if so, does the kernel provide macros or APIs for this?

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned, and unsigned overflow is well-defined, so from the language perspective you are in the clear - overflowing a `size_t` doesn't have bad consequences *by itself*. Of course the result will wrap around, so the logic of your code must be able to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size_t` doesn't overflow; it is an unsigned type, with well-defined "wraparound" semantics. Incrementing the highest value of a `size_t` results in 
zero.

In the specific case of `size_t`, in simple operations on `size_t`, like adding two sizes together, it is usually enough to just check whether the resulting operand is larger than one of the two source operands. If `(size3 = size1 + size2) < size1)`, you have a wrap.

If an unsigned type is used as a clock value which goes around a "wheel", there are macros for doing "time before" calculations correctly. For instance, we want the time `0xFFFFFFFE` to be treated as being a few time units in the past w.r.t. the time `0x00000003`. If you're using the "jiffies" time in the kernel, then you can use the `time_before` inline function, and others in that family.  (Note that there are "classic jiffies" (my term) represented as `long` and 64 bit jiffies represented as `u64`, with separate functions like `time_before` versus `time_before64`).

But are there some general macros for doing math with overflow checks? Casually combing through a kernel tree (3.18.31 that I have at my convenience), it doesn't appear that way. `grep -i overflow` on the `include` subtree doesn't come up with anything and similar searches in code areas like `fs` reveal the use of *ad hoc* locally coded overflow checks. It's a shame, really; you'd think the problem of "if I add these two `int` values together, is there a problem" is common enough that there would be a solution in place that everyone can just use like some `addv(x_int, y_int, &overflow_flag)` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

> integer overflow in kernel — possible?

Yes. It doesn't matter, user space or kernel -- it's just how CPU works.

> I'm wondering if I need to guard against possible integer overflows in the kernel

If you think that it can happen **and** it's not acceptable in your case -- then yes. For signed integers it can even lead to [undefined behavior](https://lwn.net/Articles/511259/).

> does the kernel provide macros or APIs for this

No, there are no ready-to-use functions in kernel for dealing with integer overflows. Well, there are some [GCC wrappers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html) for overflow detection... But be sure not to use it. Otherwise Linus Torvalds will come and yell at you, like [here](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1510.3/02866.html) :)

Anyway, it's quite easy to detect integer overflows manually, when you really need that. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c) for example. In your case, `size_t` is unsigned, so you only need to ensure that it doesn't wrap **or** handle wrapped value: [details](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT30-C.+Ensure+that+unsigned+integer+operations+do+not+wrap).